# How to hide or not to show specific data in material tree angular

Tags: angularjs, angular, angularjs-directive, angular-material

I have a mat-tree containing chapter and its topics ,i only maintain one database to store chapter and topic.What i want is in my mat-tree i dont want to show topicName ="default" with edit and delete icon as
have a default row for each chapter.

Here is the pic of my mat-tree
[The topic name containing default i dont want to show .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wY8vy.png)

Here is my code

```
<div class="blue-border-box">
        <mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl">
            <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodeToggle matTreeNodePadding >
              <button mat-icon-button disabled ></button>
              <label class="child-node-label" >{{node.topicName}}</label>
              <div class="d-flex">
                <button mat-icon-button (click)="editNode(node)" []><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></button>
                <button mat-icon-button (click)="deleteNode(node)"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
              </div>
            </mat-tree-node>
          
            <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasNoContent"  matTreeNodePadding>
              <button mat-icon-button disabled></button>
              <mat-form-field>
                <mat-label>New item...</mat-label>
                <input matInput #itemValue placeholder="Ex. Lettuce">
              </mat-form-field>
              <button mat-button (click)="saveNode(node, itemValue.value)">Save</button>
            </mat-tree-node>
          
            <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChild"  matTreeNodePadding>
              <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle
                      [attr.aria-label]="'Toggle ' + node.item">
                <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
                  {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
                </mat-icon>
              </button>
                <label class="head-node-label">{{node.topicName}}</label>
              <div class="d-flex">
                <button mat-icon-button (click)="editNode(node)"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></button>
                <button mat-icon-button (click)="deleteNode(node)"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
                <button mat-icon-button (click)="addNewItem(node)"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
              </div>
            </mat-tree-node>
          </mat-tree>
```

I only want topicNames which are not name as default.how and where i can put any condition to check if node.topicName ==="default" something like that.